# change theme for mutliple html files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have *themes.css (stores css variables for themes), index.html, themes.html, script.js, about_us.html* files in my project . Why does the theme not change for all the .html files?

Themes.css looks like this:

```css
body {
    --header-background-color: #1b1c27;
    --foreground: #eceff4;
    --background-color: #2e3440;
    --nav-background: #4c566a;
    --text-color-nav: #eceff4;
    --text-color-hover: #81a1c1;
    --text-color-active: #d8dee9;
    --articles-intro: #9defff;
    --team-heading: #5e81ac;

    transition: 1s;
}

body.dracula {
    --header-background-color: #282a36;
    --foreground: #f8f8f2;
    --background-color: #282a36;
    --nav-background: #44475a;
    --text-color-nav: #ff79c6;
    --text-color-hover: #8be9fd;
    --text-color-active: #50fa7b;
    --articles-intro: #bd93f9;
    --team-heading: #ff5555;

    transition: 1s;
}
```

This sets the body classes. If the body class is dracula then the theme is dracula.  It runs a script to change the theme.

script.js

```js
document.querySelector(".dracula_theme").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.className = "dracula";
});

document.querySelector(".default").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.body.className = "";
});
```

This script only changes the color of themes.html. It is run in themes.html.

So is there a better way to do this? Or Can I change something in this to get my result?

Comment: You need persist and re-apply this class when you move between pages (html files). Save this as a state in the localstorage and check for it when a page first loads

Comment: You should store your current theme somewhere and detect theme change. For example, you can store, reapply theme on page load and detect current theme change from the `localStorage` (using `storage` event).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a matter of preference, but I always use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`. In my experience it works flawlessly, and hasn't the glitches that scripts often have. Give that a try unless there are security concerns as to why you need to script the call.